# android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission ... is it required?

Tags: android

I have an application that just display Google map with some tiles as second layer. I wonder I need to use the permission `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` I copied the Google example that is available in Android SDK under Google Play store and the permission was there.

Please, notice also I included in my application "Google_Play_Services-lib". My application support minimum Android version 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, according to the [getting started documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#specify_permissions) it's used for caching map data.  Note that without it, your app should crash upon loading the map.